# Can't import csv data to table for each frames in HTML(#tablib)

Tags: python, html

I would like to import two tables in one screen

So first of all, I divided frame to 3 frames(Top, left, right)

And left and right frames should import csv data and fill up table.

Py and HTML codes dir is

```
web_test\
  └app.py
  └test.csv
   templates\
     └index.html
     └__init__.py
     └dataset1.html
     └dataset2.html
     └frame1.html
   static\
   css\
     └style.css
```

And I tried to generate code of each html & py like this

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import tablib
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
dataset1 = tablib.Dataset()
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test.csv')) as f:
    dataset1.csv = f.read()
dataset2 = tablib.Dataset()
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test.csv')) as f:
    dataset2.csv = f.read()

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/dataset1")
def dataset1():
    data1= dataset1.html
    # return dataset.html
    return render_template('dataset1.html', data=data1)

@app.route("/dataset2")
def dataset2():
    data2 = dataset2.html
    # return dataset.html
    return render_template('dataset2.html', data=data2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<Frameset rows = "17%, 1*" border="0">
    <frame src ="../frame1.html" name="frame1" scrolling ="no", marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
        <Frameset cols="30%,*">
            <Frame src = "../dataset1.html" name="dataset1" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
            <frame src ="../dataset2.html" name="dataset2" scrolling ="no", marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
        </Frameset>
</Frameset>

<BODY>
</BODY>
</html>
```

**dataset1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dataset1</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This dataset1</h1>
    <div class = "table">
        {%block body %}
        {{data|safe}}
        {% endblock%}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**dataset2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dataset2</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This dataset2</h1>
    <div class = "table">
        {%block body %}
        {{data|safe}}
        {% endblock%}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**frame1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
Test
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run these codes,
frames are showing but its contents are not visualized
I tried to figure out which one is wrong
but it was so hard to find the solution

Did any code wrong?
or dir of each codes are wrong?

I hope someone may give me advice

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your routes you set data1 and data2 to be data1.html and data2.html respectively. That should probably be data1.csv and data2.csv.

Comment: I found why tables didn't showed up, its because of table were not designated as html as like you said, so I modified data1 as table                          
 data1= dataset1.html   -> table = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("path")      data=data1 -> data=table.to_html()                                                                      Thx for your advice. And now the last problem is that table won't showed in index page :(